# Replacing commas and dots in R

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I have a whole column of numbers that include dot separators at the thousands and comma instead of dot as an dismal separator. When I try to create a numeric column out of them, I lose all data.

```
var1 <- c("50,0", "72,0", "960,0", "1.920,0", "50,0", "50,0", "960,0")
df <- cbind(var1, var2 = as.numeric(gsub(".", "", as.character(var1))))
```

and wound up with:

```
 var1      var2
[1,] "50,0"    NA  
[2,] "72,0"    NA  
[3,] "960,0"   NA  
[4,] "1.920,0" NA  
[5,] "50,0"    NA  
[6,] "50,0"    NA  
[7,] "960,0"   NA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to escape the `"."` in your regular expression, and you need to replace the commas with a `"."` before you can convert to numeric.

```
> as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", var1)))
[1]   50   72  960 1920   50   50  960
```

Comment: ``format(var1, decimal.mark = '.')`` is an alternative way to change commas into dots. Can't say about pros and cons, it was just a side comment.

Comment: When I pass this function a numeric vector it returns the error ` Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Answer (score 10):

For things like these I like `scan()` the most, because it is easy to understand. Just use

```
scan(text=var1, dec=",", sep=".")
```

Alas, it's not faster than `gsub()`, which on the other hand seemes overpowered. Hence another, and fast, option is `sub()`:

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", sub(".", "", var1, fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE))
```

And just in case: When you're reading `var1` from a file directly, just read it in with a specified separator: `read.table("file.txt", dec=",", sep=".")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use function "type_convert", from "readr" package. I am reading an ODS file (Locale Portuguese), and converting the numbers:

```
library('readODS')
library('tidyverse')
data <- read_ods('mod-preditivo.ods', sheet=1,col_names = TRUE,range='a1:b30',col_types=NA)
df <- type_convert(data,trim_ws=TRUE,col_types = cols(Pesos=col_integer(),Alturas=col_double()),locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))
str(df)
```